# Website2APK with Android

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I'm relatively new to coding so I have a website that I wanted to convert to an APK to upload to Google Play, so as I'm relatively new I used the program website2apk, all that went OK so when I went to upload it to Google Play I had this error
"
Unoptimised APK
Warning:

This APK results in unused code and resources being sent to users. Your app could be smaller if you used the Android App Bundle. By not optimising your app for device configurations, your app is larger to download and install on users' devices than it needs to be. Larger apps see lower installation success rates and take up storage on users' devices.

Resolution:

Use the Android App Bundle to automatically optimise for device configurations, or manage it yourself with multiple APKs."

So I installed Android Studio and tried importing the APK and the build is greyed out.

So decompiled it and tried importing the project, However I try to import it I get this (see the screenshot: http://prntscr.com/o2aoak).
So from there I'm clueless on what to do as I have tried both options and both don't seem to work.
Then when I tried create project from existing files it said I need to migrate to Gradle and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Have a look at [this article](https://abhiandroid.com/createandroidapp/webview-android-app), hope you will find it helpful for your case.

Comment: Thanks ever so much for this, got everything sorted.